# Family of equivalent unitary representations is not a set.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

I have recently come across a statement in the book: *Kazhdan's property (T) by B. Bekka, P. de la Harpe, A. Valette* at the beginning  Appendix F.2. *Fell topology on sets of unitary representations.*

> Let $G$ be a topological group. One would like to define a topology on the family of equivalences classes of unitary representations of $G$. There is a problem
>   since this family is not a set.

Can anyone elaborate on this, why is this family not a set (when $G$ is not locally compact abelian or compact)?

Comment: It has nothing to do with groups. The collection of all vector spaces (over a given field) of a fixed dimension is not a set. There are too many of them. It's a proper class, if you work in a set theory having proper classes, in ZFC, such a collection simply doesn't exist.

Comment: @DanielFischer So if I consider only finite groups and take the class of equivalent representations, would this also not be a set for the same reasons?

Comment: @Chris: yes. Even if your group is the trivial group. Then a unitary rep of the trivial group up to equivalence is the same as a Hilbert space up to isomorphism. And isomorphism classes of Hilbert spaces are indexed by all cardinals, so there is no set of Hilbert spaces containing all isomorphisms classes.